# if (columnArow1= columnArow2, columnBrow2, "") excel if(logic_test, [value_if_true],[value_if_false]) how can I write this in python?

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I would like to write Excel code into a Python (pandas)

I have filtered the `df.loc[df.Activity_Mailbox.isnull()]`, now the na values must be calculated using

```
if (columnArow1 = columnArow2, columnBrow2, "")
```

This formula is according to Excel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please provide next time some demo data, like in your other question :-)
If I understand you correctly. Your data looks like:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"A":[1,2,3,np.nan,5,np.nan], 
                  "B":[10,11,12,13,14,15]})
df

    A       B
0   1.0     10
1   2.0     11
2   3.0     12
3   NaN     13
4   5.0     14
5   NaN     15
```

And now you want to fill the `NaN` with value from the other column. This can easily be done with:

```
df["A"] = df["A"].fillna(df["B"])
```

**Output:**

```
df

    A       B
0   1.0     10
1   2.0     11
2   3.0     12
3   13.0    13
4   5.0     14
5   15.0    15
```

Comment: Thank you @Marco_CH. Awesome!